# iOS - Dismiss keyboard on Return key

Tags: ios, swift

I am working with a `UITextView` and I need to dismiss the keyboard by pressing return key. 
This is what I'm doing:

```
class MyController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var writeNote: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.writeNote.delegate = self
}
```

how to proceed? When using a `UITextField` I would simply call the delegate for `textFieldShouldReturn` method but I don't appear to find anything like that for a textView. I can not use a textField because I need a larger amount of rows. The TextView tooltip says "When a user taps a text view, a keyboard appears; when a user taps Return in the keyboard, the keyboard disappears and..." but it doesn't do it by default..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextView doesn't have any such direct delegate method to hide the keyboard. You have to work around with the `shouldChangeTextInRange: replacementText`method.
In this method, you can check for a new line character and if you get one, you can resign.

Comment: This worked perfectly with the "\n" line, thank you very much!